# div escapes parent when the browser loads

Tags: html

This is a really weird issue and I'm 100% sure I'm closing my html correctly.

If I have more then two child divs, it'll escape the parent. Literally.

So this works:

```
<div class="info-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-title">Why would you buy Buy LoL Account?</div>
        <div class="info-description">
            Are you searching for an affordable high-quality League of Legends account? You’ve come to the right place. 
            We sell Smurf accounts with impressive rankings, from Diamond, Silver, Gold, and even Platinum but the big question 
            is why should you buy from us and not the other online sellers? 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="info-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-title">Buy LoL Smurfs Accounts</div>
        A Smurf is an account owned by a player who has another level 30 account. The Smurf account is mainly used for training purposes against other more skilled opponents. We have Smurfs accounts already in level 30 so you won’t need to level them higher again. These will provide you with the quickest way to amass riot points and rise to level 30 in League of Legends. When you buy Smurfs account from us, it will be delivered instantly with all the necessary instructions.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However if I add one more:

```
<div class="info-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-title">Why would you buy Buy LoL Account?</div>
        <div class="info-description">
            Are you searching for an affordable high-quality League of Legends account? You’ve come to the right place. 
            We sell Smurf accounts with impressive rankings, from Diamond, Silver, Gold, and even Platinum but the big question 
            is why should you buy from us and not the other online sellers? 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="info-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-title">Buy LoL Smurfs Accounts</div>
        A Smurf is an account owned by a player who has another level 30 account. The Smurf account is mainly used for training purposes against other more skilled opponents. We have Smurfs accounts already in level 30 so you won’t need to level them higher again. These will provide you with the quickest way to amass riot points and rise to level 30 in League of Legends. When you buy Smurfs account from us, it will be delivered instantly with all the necessary instructions.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="info-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-title">Buy LoL Smurfs Accounts</div>
        A Smurf is an account owned by a player who has another level 30 account. The Smurf account is mainly used for training purposes against other more skilled opponents. We have Smurfs accounts already in level 30 so you won’t need to level them higher again. These will provide you with the quickest way to amass riot points and rise to level 30 in League of Legends. When you buy Smurfs account from us, it will be delivered instantly with all the necessary instructions.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get this:

[image]

But it does not look like that in my editor:

```
   <div class="info-container">

            <div class="info-box">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info-title">Why would you buy Buy LoL Account?</div>
                <div class="info-description">
                    Are you searching for an affordable high-quality League of Legends account? You’ve come to the right place. 
                    We sell Smurf accounts with impressive rankings, from Diamond, Silver, Gold, and even Platinum but the big question 
                    is why should you buy from us and not the other online sellers? 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info-title">Buy LoL Smurfs Accounts</div>
                A Smurf is an account owned by a player who has another level 30 account. The Smurf account is mainly used for training purposes against other more skilled opponents. We have Smurfs accounts already in level 30 so you won’t need to level them higher again. These will provide you with the quickest way to amass riot points and rise to level 30 in League of Legends. When you buy Smurfs account from us, it will be delivered instantly with all the necessary instructions.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info-title">Get a Ready-Made League of Legends Lvl 30 Account</div>
                <div class="info-description">
                If you are interested in having your own already developed League of Legends lvl 30 account, then you are in the right place. A level 30 they comes with numerous benefits. If you are a new player, you’ll begin at level 1, which is limited in the number of Champions, summoner spells, masteries, runes, and game modes you have. It’s a very boring level to start from. As you continue playing, you gradually unlock more game features but truth be told, it can take a really long time to unlock the most critical features. You need to reach level 30 to unlock features that allow you to play ranked matches, which are where all the fun in LoL is found. We provide you with a faster way to get to this level. Simply buy a level 30 account and begin playing those exciting ranked matches right away. You don’t need to spend months trying to level up.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info-title">The Difference Between Unranked and Ranked Accounts</div>
                <div class="info-description">
                The major difference between an unranked and a ranked League of Legends account can be described as the difference between playing a normal casual game and playing a highly competitive game. Ranked matches are more exciting and highly competitive than unranked accounts, adding fun and enjoyment to the game. You cannot play a ranked game until you have a level 30 summoner, Ranked BlazingBoost, and 16 Champions. We have ranked accounts that are ready for competitive matches. With our already developed level 30 League of Legends account, you can begin playing exciting ranked matches immediately. 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="info-title">Get NA or EUW Accounts</div>
                <div class="info-description">
                You can buy a LoL account from us regardless of your location. We sell uranked accounts for different geographic regions including North America and EUW. Players from the US and Canada are usually connected via the NA server while their European counterparts connect via the EUW server. 
        We have both ranked and unranked accounts for different regions. They are all safe accounts that you can use without fear of running into a sudden ban. We also provide safe payment processing and instant delivery for accounts in every region worldwide. 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra `</div>` in your code which is because you haven't add `<div class="info-description">` for the second and third child nodes, try this:

```
<div class="info-container">
<div class="info-box">
<div class="container">
    <div class="info-title">Why would you buy Buy LoL Account?</div>
    <div class="info-description">
            Are you searching for an affordable high-quality League of Legends account? You’ve come to the right place. 
            We sell Smurf accounts with impressive rankings, from Diamond, Silver, Gold, and even Platinum but the big question 
            is why should you buy from us and not the other online sellers? 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="info-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-title">Buy LoL Smurfs Accounts</div>
<div class="info-description">
        A Smurf is an account owned by a player who has another level 30 account. The Smurf account is mainly used for training purposes against other more skilled opponents. We have Smurfs accounts already in level 30 so you won’t need to level them higher again. These will provide you with the quickest way to amass riot points and rise to level 30 in League of Legends. When you buy Smurfs account from us, it will be delivered instantly with all the necessary instructions.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="info-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info-title">Buy LoL Smurfs Accounts</div>
<div class="info-description">
        A Smurf is an account owned by a player who has another level 30 account. The Smurf account is mainly used for training purposes against other more skilled opponents. We have Smurfs accounts already in level 30 so you won’t need to level them higher again. These will provide you with the quickest way to amass riot points and rise to level 30 in League of Legends. When you buy Smurfs account from us, it will be delivered instantly with all the necessary instructions.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

to avoid such problems try using IDEs they have basic functionalities to check correctness of the HTML.